# How to store and verify a list of user provided answers with MongoDB and express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

A newbie with React-Redux here

I am developing a testing application for users to give tests on. It consists of multiple choice questions, with some questions having multiple options as answers also. (MERN Stack)

Currently, I make a POST request on each option click. If a user has selected multiple options or just one option for a question, I store the answer choices inside an array with a user and question Id reference.

Also, I had stored a list of correct answers in the MongoDB for each question in arrays too. For each user answer provided by user, I also have to keep a track of whether it was answered correctly or not for which I have a key called 'didPass' in the mongo schema for the Answer table.

I am facing the following two issues with this:

1) For each click on a option for a question, a POST request is made. If the answer already exists, an update is made else a new record is created. Simultaneously, I also have to check if the answer provided is correct which involves two array traversals - one for the user provided answers against the list of current answers to check and update the 'didPass' key.

2)There might be essay questions incorporated later also, and storing an essay response inside an array seems incorrect.

Would anyone be able to recommend a better way of achieving this functionality (instead of using arrays and making a POST request for each option click) ?

P.S. I am using async/await so the pyramid of doom is not an issue

Answer (score 0):

Make one 'POST' request when the user submits the form. Making database calls for each answer is going to put a lot of overhead when you scale. Instead, try the following solutions:

1. Make a 'GET' request to fetch all the answers from MongoDB in one go, before you load the test app
2. Store the 'master answer key' in redux store.
3. Make a copy of the redux store in 'localStorage', in case the user accidentally closes the app or the browser, he can resume the test without losing data. This will give the app some form of permanence.
4. Now, store each response in Redux store.
5. When, user submits the test, calculate the score based of data stored in Redux store.
6. Save the final test score and test taker's choice in MongoDB for future reference.
7. Add whatever features that your app needs.

Comment: I do not understand it completely. I did not use a redux store since there could be many tests in the database as we might later have a CMS for inputting a test to the mongo db